# GORM one-to-one with grails scaffolding?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain object `Department` that has a one-to-one relationship with another domain object `DepartmentPreference`. When I try to generate the scaffolding controller for `Department`, I'm left with a pull-down menu to select the `DepartmentPreference`. Since there is none yet (because `DepartmentPreference` has a `belongsTo = Department`), I can't create one.

What's the best solution you can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created a controller/view for DepartmentPreference like you did for Department? if not you'll need to create one or add/modify what ever existing controller/view to handle that functionality.

Since you mentioned scaffolding - I'm assuming your **Department controller** is defined like one of the following:

```
class DepartmentController {
  static scaffold = true
  ..
}
```

or

```
class SomeController {
  static scaffold = Department
  ..
}
```

If this **Department controller** - was auto generated or define with just scaffold, then it's only providing CRUD operations for Department and not any other domain classes (at least not directly). There are lot's of ways to add the missing DepartmentPreference functionality, but probably the fastest for you is to use what ever method you use to create the **Department controller** on the DepartmentPreference as well.

Comment: Sure, I guess I wasn't clear enough in the question. The DepartmentPreferenceController requires a reference to an existing department, and the DepartmentController requires a reference to an existing DepartmentPreference. Ideally both these objects would need to be created in the same transaction.

Comment: Just add custom logic that would provide a form to capture both Department and DepartmentPreference info, then submit to a custom action on your controllers (probably DepartmentController since it sounds like Department is the owning entity). You can define the custom logic in either your scaffolded controller or use **generate-controller** command to generate the default CRUD actions and then update the one of the actions with your custom logic. In any case you basically need some custom logic to do what you want, Grails scaffold feature will not provide what you need by default.

Comment: Makes sense. It's good to get confirmation that it's not something provided by default.